# How to get program name in perl

Tags: perl

According to the section for C programmers in "perltrap" and to everything I googled, I should use "$0" to get the program name in Perl. However, when I run the following "caller" script:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

exec{"./called"}("name", "arg");
```

which itself calls the following "called" script:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

print("$0 $ARGV[0]\n");
```

I get "`./called arg`" instead!

If I call the following "called.c" program instead from "caller":

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
        printf("%s %s\n", argv[0], argv[1]);
        return 0;
}
```

I get "`name arg`" as expected.

Is there a way to get the script name, not the path?

Comment: Not sure I get your point. If you call `printf "%s %s\n", $ARGV[0], $ARGV[1]` from Perl you also get the first and second argument to the program. I am sure that if you try to "exec" the string "called" from C, you would get the same result as in Perl. What is it you think your code is supposed to do?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? $0 refers to command line arguments - because you started your script with a 'command' of `./called` then that's the first arg.

Comment: No. I tried your code, and what I get is "`arg`", not "`name arg`". See my answer to M42 to understand what I'm trying to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some more tests with Bash, Python and even a custom script interpreter, I found out that the Shebang mechanism will not propagate "argv[0]" to the interpreter, but will use the path after the shebang as "argv[0]" for the interpreter. I guess this is a feature of C programs that cannot be emulated in scripts.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [basename](http://perldoc.perl.org/File/Basename.html) core module:

```
use File::Basename;
my $script_name = basename($0);
```

Comment: No. With this, I just get "`called arg`" instead of "`./called arg`". What I expect is "`name arg`", just like in C.

Comment: @airman: In your example, the script name is `called` not `name`.

Comment: what I call "name" is the name given to the script by the process which exec it. This is not always equal to the basename of the path (at least on Unix platforms, I don't know how it is on Windows). This is very useful when you need to implement a series of commands with only one executable. You just need to add symlinks to it.